How to deactivate plugin when WooCommerce plugin is not active and show error to user?
Here is my custom plugin code
custom-plugin.php code
include_once FBPE_PLUGIN_PATH . 'inc/class-free-bulk-price-editor.php';
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array('Free_Bulk_Price_Editor', 'activate'));
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, array('Free_Bulk_Price_Editor', 'deactivate'));

class file code:
class Free_Bulk_Price_Editor {
    public static function is_woocommerce_active() {
        return class_exists('WooCommerce');
    }

    public static function activate() {
        if (!self::is_woocommerce_active()) {
            deactivate_plugins('free-bulk-wp-price-upgrade/free-bulk-wp-price-upgrade.php');
            wp_admin_notice( 'There was an error!', [ 'type' => 'error' ] );
            return;
        }
    }
}

This not work according to my requirements I want my plugin only active when WooCommerce is active.
I want to build custom wordpress plugin and want my plugin is active only when WooCommerce is active other wise show error to user that WooCommerce is required to active this plugin.

As of WordPress 6.5 you can list the dependency in your plugin header. At a certain point, accounting for people using your plugin in unexpected ways has diminishing returns. In your plugin bootup, you can check if Woo is active and just bail early if it isn't.

if you add the line in your plugin code like below
/*
Plugin Name:  your pluign name
Plugin URI:   url
Description:  A short little description of the plugin.
Version:      1.0
Author:       author name
Requires Plugins: woocommerce
*/

